# How to get QueryDeepPartialEntity or same type for create entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, prisma

QueryDeepPartialEntit this is type for creation entities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt4Iq.png)

How to do something similar in typeorm, for example, in prisma these types can be obtained like this Prisma.Enumerable<Prisma.FactorsCreateManyInput>

I want to do some like this

```
const userPayload: QueryDeepPartialEntity<User> = [];

    userPayload.push({
      age: 12,
      id: 0,
      firstName: "",
      lastName1: "",
    });

    const queryBuilder = AppDataSource.createQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.insert().into(User).values(userPayload);
```